# CMake, OS X Wrong Python Version

Tags: c++, qt, python-2.7, cmake

I am trying to use / learn CMake to embed Python into a C++ application that uses Qt.

I am using FIND_PACKAGE in an attempt to get a non-system package installation (Anaconda Python 2.7.9) in.  I can not get the compiler to see any version other than the system installation (version 2.7.5).

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
#Minimum CMAKE version
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0)

#Name the project
PROJECT(embedpython)

#Set the version number
SET(embedpython_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
SET(embedpython_VERSION_MINOR 1)

SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 4.8.6 REQUIRED QtGui QtCore)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(embedpython_HEADERS_MOC ${embedpython_HEADERS})
message(status "QT FOUND: ${Qt4_FOUND}")

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 2.7.9 REQUIRED)
message(status "libs found: ${PYTHONLIBS_FOUND}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES: ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "PYTHONLIBS_VERSION: ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

SET(embedpython_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    pythonutilsimpl.cpp
    ipcepythonrunner.cpp)

SET(embedpython_HEADERS
    mainwindow.h
    pythonutilsimpl.h
    ipcepythonutils.h
    ipcepythonrunner.h)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(embedpython ${embedpython_SOURCES} ${embedpython_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(embedpython ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Which outputs:

```
cmpt:build user$ /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake .. && make
statusQT FOUND: TRUE
statuslibs found: TRUE
-- PYTHON_LIBRARIES: /home/me/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: /home/me/anaconda/include/python2.7
-- PYTHONLIBS_VERSION: 2.7.9
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS: /home/me/anaconda/include/python2.7
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/Desktop/EmbedPython/build
Scanning dependencies of target embedpython_automoc
[ 16%] Automatic moc for target embedpython
Generating moc_mainwindow.cpp
[ 16%] Built target embedpython_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target embedpython
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedpython.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedpython.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedpython.dir/pythonutilsimpl.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedpython.dir/ipcepythonrunner.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/embedpython.dir/embedpython_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable embedpython
[100%] Built target embed python
```

Using ccmake, I have set PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR and PYTHON_LIBRARY so that FIND_PACKAGE succeeds in finding Python 2.7.9.

Within the C++ I have a debug to print the python version and path.  Without fail, this returns Python 2.7.5.  What is required in the CMake file to get the version of Python at the PATH I am aiming for?